# Optimistic UI updates in RxSwift

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I have a view model that makes some updates to an array of todos.  I'm mapping a set of inputs to actions (modeled as cases in an enum) and merging them into a single

```swift
let mergedActions = Observable<TodosAction>.merge([
    todosFromService.map { .fromService(todos: $0) },
    toggleFavoriteSubject.map { .toggleFavorite(identifier: $0) },
    toggleIsReadSubject.map { .toggleIsRead(identifier: $0) }
])
```

Then I'm using `scan` to "remember" the history of the updates.

```swift
todos = mergedActions
    .scan([]) { (lastTodos, new) -> [Todo] in
        switch new {
        case .fromService(let todos):
            return todos
        case .toggleFavorite(let identifier):
            return lastTodos.withFavoritedToggled(atId: identifier)
        case .toggleIsRead(let identifier):
            return lastTodos.withIsReadToggled(atId: identifier)
        }
    }
```

My problem is integrating the network requests into this approach.  E.g. I have the "optimistic update" where I'm assuming success and updating the todo in memory.  But I also want to update it on the server and 
"roll back" that update if the request fails.

I can't think of how to do this based on the current structure of my Observables.  E.g. the `scan` closure is no longer in the world of Observables as it just returns a `[Todo]` so I can't make api requests with `flatMap` or anything.

How could this be amended or augmented to support api integration and roll back the corresponding local updates if the remote updates fail?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to aggregate state as this framework does - https://github.com/maxvol/RaspSwift
It also relies heavily on *.scan()* operator, so you will find the approach familiar.
You can either use it, or just implement a similar solution yourself.